# Woocommerce OAuth1 Authentication

Tags: wordpress, api, oauth, woocommerce

Good Day. I am following woocommerce's api documentation on the http authentication section (http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication-over-http) but I cant do it. Their documentation is a little bit outdaettd because the links are not working anymore.

My URL is

```
http://url/wp-json/wc/v2/products
```

Parameters are:

```
oauth_consumer_key: (consumerkey)
oauth_timestamp: 2017-12-29T13:30:43.UTC 
oauth_nonce: c2b6owrij6
oauth_signature_method: HMAC-SHA1
```

I made the signature base string using https://www.url-encode-decode.com/.
I generated the signature using https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html wherein the wc consumer secret is used for the secret key. Then after that, I used postman to make an api call.

Below is the error I got.

```
"code": "woocommerce_rest_authentication_error",
"message": "Invalid signature - provided signature does not match.",
"data": {
    "status": 401
}
```

Please help

Comment: look here, there is a list of clients at the end of the page : https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/

Comment: @mmm HI, I tried doing the steps there. It still did not work for me...
It said 'Fatal error: Call to undefined method WC_API_Client::get_orders()'